# Share URI/Text on Android TV displays Turn on Bluetooth Dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tv, android-sharing

I want to share an image with other apps in my Android **TV** application. I upload the image when the user clicks on a button and I want to share its URL (as text) or URI. So, this is my code:

```
val bitmap = ......
btnAccept.setOnClickListener {
            val userId = Storage.getInstance(playerView.context).getUserId()
            vm.storeImageInDatabase(userId, bitmap, ::onImageUploadedSuccessfully)
        }

private fun onImageUploadedSuccessfully(url: String) {
        val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url)
            type = "text/plain"
        }
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share"))
    }
```

I have even changed `onImageUploadedSuccessfully()` to the following method in order to share the URI.

```
private fun onImageUploadedSuccessfully(url: String) {
        val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url))
            type = "image/jpg"
        }
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share"))
    }
```

However, the result is the same. Following Dialog displays and ask me to enable the Bluetooth. I click on `TURN ON` button but nothing happens. This dialogue displays again and again whenever my upload is successful. Therefore, I am unable to share anything.

Any idea if sharing on TV app is different than the mobile app?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the type of URI you want to share with other apps you might have to search into their developer's sites, given that an application should have intent filters accepting data from outside apps.

Let's out the same scenario for your app, if you develop your application to do not receive any data from outside your app the

```
Intent.createChooser
```

will never show your app in the options to share.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: Thanks Jose. I understand if I get "No app can perform this action" but this Bluetooth dialogue is strange to me.

Comment: I am reading more since I am curious and I found some news related to Google disabling the feature of sharing photos.

https://www.theverge.com/2019/3/4/18250552/google-disables-android-tv-photo-sharing-account-privacy-issue

[original weet ](https://twitter.com/wothadei/status/1102089147596992512 )

this is the tweet which started everything, there might be some changes that are going on on the platform if I find something useful I will share it here.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. Thanks for investigation. Anyways, my team decided to disable the feature yesterday due to some privacy reasons. It might be a bug on Emulator, I had not had time to test it on an STB or Android TV so far.